# Compare values in a same row

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has status report like below

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M58Bt.png)

I have got a query that can compare the status in a row and if it changes from the last week data, it flags

```
SELECT t_next.*
FROM table t_prev
JOIN table t_next
ON t_next.`Node` = t_prev.`Node`
   AND t_next.`Parameter` = t_prev.`Parameter`
   AND t_next.`Status` != t_prev.`Status`
   AND date(t_next.`DOR`) > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND date(t_next.`TOI`) = date(t_prev.`TOI`) + INTERVAL 7 day
WHERE t_next.`Status` = ‘Un-healthy’
```

Query Output

[Query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKvun.png)

I want to make this query better by making the current week data as a baseline and compare with all the week's data and not just the prev week data so that I can see the trend

Like below

1st row - Compare current week with prev week (7 days back)
2nd row - Compare current week with 2 weeks back data (14 days back)
3nd row - Compare current week with 3 weeks back data (21 days back)

And so on.....

Comment: This is a "solve this for me" question.  Stack Overflow is meant to be a "what am I doing wrong here" forum.  Please add comments about what you have already tried.

Comment: I posted the query which I came up with, and able to compare with the value 7 days back, but I am not sure on how to gather the distinct value for DOR column and do foreach (like how I normally do in PowerShell), so came here for some guidance. Thanks